# Open android app via ssh

Tags: android

I have SSHDroid installed on my Android Device, and I've been investigating how to launch an app via SSH.

I can't seem to find any solution, nor documentation that explain why shouldn't I be able to do such thing.

How can I achieve to launch an app via SSH (computer to android) not using ADB? Is it even possible?

Comment: You can call it starting a intent with `am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname` from the remote shell , but you may need the root access

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in this way:

```
ssh mymobile /su/bin/su -c am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

`su` is run because it sets proper environment. Without it, the `am` fails.

I'm running openssh server on my mobile and login as root.